# Edit Macro in Excel 365 Desktop; Convert Shipment Tracking IDs to Clickable Links

Tags: excel, vba

A few years ago, I created a macro in Excel named "HyperAdd", which takes a UPS tracking number (i.e. `1Z2976592400929202`) and transforms it into a clickable link like so:

```
http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums=1Z2976592400929202
```

I have been using this macro every week for many years with no problem. However, the service provider recently added FedEx as an option for those sites outside the continental US, so I need to modify the macro to conditionally generate appropriate links based upon the format of the tracking ID. When I go to edit the macro in the latest version of Excel 365, like so:

[image: Macro Window]

I cannot find the code anywhere in the VBA editor:

[image: VBA Editor Window]

I have searched everywhere in the editor, and even checked for any settings that might have an impact, and found nothing. Where else can I look? I *know* it is in there, somewhere.

---

### UPDATE and Final Solution

Thanks to quick help from @rotabor, I was able to recover my code. If anyone is interested in how I solved the problem at hand, here is the final code:

```
Sub HyperAdd()
    
    ' Converts each selected tracking ID into a clickable hyperlink.
    ' Differentiates between FedEx and UPS based upon the ID format.
    ' Does not change cells that do not contain valid tracking IDs.
    '
    ' Usage:
    '     1) Select the cells or columns that contain tracking IDs
    '     2) Press <Alt>+<F8>
    '     3) Select HyperAdd in the Macro Name pane
    '     4) Click the <Run> button in the right column
    
    Dim CurrentLink As String
    Dim CurrentTip As String
    Dim ValidTrackingID As Boolean
    
    FedExLink = "https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?trknbr="
    FedExTip = "Click to get updated tracking info on FedEx package: "
    UPSLink = "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums="
    UPSTip = "Click to get updated tracking info on UPS package: "
    
    For Each xCell In Selection
        
        ValidTrackingID = False
        
        ' FedEx tracking number
        If xCell.Value Like "############" Then
            ValidTrackingID = True
            CurrentLink = FedExLink & xCell.Value
            CurrentTip = FedExTip & xCell.Value
        
        ' UPS tracking number
        ElseIf xCell.Value Like "1Z################" Then
            ValidTrackingID = True
            CurrentLink = UPSLink & xCell.Value
            CurrentTip = UPSTip & xCell.Value
        
        End If
        
        ' Modify only cells that have valid tracking ID
        If ValidTrackingID = True Then
            
            ' Insert clickable link
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, _
                Address:=CurrentLink, _
                ScreenTip:=CurrentTip, _
                TextToDisplay:=xCell.Value
            
            ' Set font back to Ariel
            xCell.Font.Name = "Ariel"
            
        End If
    
    Next xCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just double-click on Module1 in the left pane.

What I noted strange in the screenshot - workbook's name should appear in the title of VBA window like "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications - FPAC ...". Looks like a bug.

If no result, try to export Module1 (from its context menu). Edit text and import it back.

Try to "save the workbook as" to create its copy, it can help.

Comment: Neither double-click nor right-click -> View Code did anything, but I was able to export Module1 as a .bas file, import it back and then I am able to see the code and edit it. Many thanks for getting me past this hurdle!