# Excel Clickable Hyperlinks Within Text

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have a spreadsheet that I update and send out weekly to my customers; in this file there is a tab named `FAQs` which contains common questions and answers to them, like so:

[image: Sample FAQ Entry]

I would like to include clickable hyperlinks within the text, like the fake one in bullet #1 above (it is just plain text formatted as underline). Has anyone found a way to include hyperlinks within larger blocks of text within a cell?

Comment: What have  you tried? Surely there are lots of resources that provide some possible solutions if you google how to do this.

Comment: I HAVE Googled this for years now, and have found no answer; THAT is why I posted here. Based upon what I have learned thus far, I would not be surprised to find out that it is an impossible task. It is VERY possible to make the whole cell a hyperlink like my recent post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77232804/edit-macro-in-excel-365-desktop-convert-shipment-tracking-ids-to-clickable-link/77232852#77232852 discusses. But to insert a link inside a block of text, that has proven a bit elusive.

Comment: But [your question gives us no indication of what you have tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)...and that's why I asked.

Comment: That's a good point, and I will modify the post later today to include my prior eforts with this, which are rather numerous. Thank you for your effort for clarification on this.